# Taking pictures while recording a video

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-galaxy-s-3, camera, video, photos

How can I take pictures while recording a video, similar to the feature introduced in the Galaxy S3 or is that a hardware feature?

If the feature is available (e.g., via an app), which handsets and android versions are supported?

Comment: Personally, I'm interested in the Galaxy S2 but the feature may be of interest to other handset owners as well

Comment: Itamar, I strongly suggest you to re-phrase your question: *Is there an app for X* is listed being off topic (see our [FAQ]). I'd rather ask "how can I take pictures while recording a video". Very likely the answers will be similar, nevertheless -- but you avoid your question being closed before the answers are there :)